# how to integrate over even numbers?

Tags: integration

I understand that

$$
Area = \int_0^{10} xdx
$$

gives the area under a triangle from x=0 to x=10 where the hypotenuse is the line y=x.

But suppose I have  bar graph where the width of each bar is 1. I know I can manually calculate the area of each bar and then add them up. And I know I can select the odd values of x and use those bars to sum. And I know I can write an excel macro to do that. But I am interested in a mathematical solution. Sometimes the bar graph is not a simple line. It can be a parabola or even something like y=x*sin(x/.3) The even numbers here are peaks only

[Here](http://graphsketch.com/?eqn1_color=1&eqn1_eqn=x*sin(x%2F.3)&eqn2_color=2&eqn2_eqn=&eqn3_color=3&eqn3_eqn=&eqn4_color=4&eqn4_eqn=&eqn5_color=5&eqn5_eqn=&eqn6_color=6&eqn6_eqn=&x_min=-17&x_max=20&y_min=-40&y_max=40&x_tick=1&y_tick=1&x_label_freq=5&y_label_freq=5&do_grid=0&do_grid=1&bold_labeled_lines=0&bold_labeled_lines=1&line_width=4&image_w=850&image_h=525)

This question can be generalized to ask - can I integrate over a subset of real numbers?

Comment: It depends on your measure : for the measure of Lebesgue, it will be zero because $\mathbb{Z}$ negligible. But if you use the counting measure on $\mathbb{Z}$ (i.e. a Dirac measure at each element of $\mathbb{Z}$), then your integral will not be zero for sure.

Comment: Do you mean integrating over subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ such as $[1,2], [3,4], [5,6],...$? If you mean only the odd numbers $\{1,3,5,...,9\}\subset [0,10]$ then the interval is zero, as noted by Nicolas.

Comment: Indeed, the question seems like you're looking for the precursor to integration, summation.

Answer (score 2):

Well, if I understand correctly, you are working with histograms and you would like to know the area of a subset of the histogram.

In order to do that, if your histogram has a fixed width, then it's just a finite sum : 
$A = \sum_{i=1}^k{m_i}$, where $m_i$ is the height of the $i$th bar. (Hence its area since you have fixed the width at 1.)

Now you want to know the area of the histogram restricted to the even $i$, so you have :
$$A = \sum_{j=1}^{\lfloor k/2 \rfloor}{m_{2j}}$$

So in general, for a given subset, in order to be able to do that, what you need to do is to find out how you can write a finite sum covering this subset.

I'm sorry if I misunderstood your first question, please complete it if it's the case.

For the "generalised question" since I don't think it's really an generalisation of your question, I won't try to answer it.

Comment: thank you. Can i sum the even numbers just by multiplying x by in the integral so instead of x from 0 to 10 in my example above, i would use x=0 to 5 and change the integral to 2*x.? Although this works for a linear function, I don't know if it's valid for a function like x* sin(x/.3) where the function would become 2x* sin(2x/.3)

Comment: Sorry, I missed your comment 10 days ago. 
Well, it all depends on the "width" of your bars : in the case of x*sin(x/.3) having a width of 1 doesn't make so much sense to me.
Actually an integral isn't like "the area of a bar graph with width 1", it is more like "the area of a bar graph with width going to 0". You may want to read more about "Darboux sums", maybe.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you want not to integrate over the even numbers (which would mean bars of width $0$ which would not contribute to the area), but to have an every even numbered bar summation expressed as integral:
$$
I = \int\sum_{k=0}^\infty f(2k) [H(x- 2k) - H(x- (2k+1))] \, dx
$$

where $H$ is the Heaviside function.

Example:

[image]

Comment: oh my! The heavy side function! I have some learning to do. yes that's what I want. But it's like me asking for the location of the holy grail and you telling me in LAtin (which I do not speak). thank you though for your effort- now for some heavy side learning.

Comment: summing rectangles was just a simple example. I also gave a more complex curve, x*sin(x/.3)

Comment: same boundaries, x= 0 to 10 but only for odd upper limits for example , x=0 to 1, then 2 to 3, then 4 to 5, then 6 to 7...

Comment: Let us just consider the first interval: are we talking $$A = f(0) \times 1$$ or $$A = f(1) \times 1$$ or $$A = \int\limits_0^1 f(x) dx$$ here?

Comment: the third option. thanks for reading-I know I wasn't so clear.

Comment: Have you tried Wolfram Alpha? ([Example](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int_0^1+x+sin%28x%2F3%29+dx+%2B+int_2^3+x+sin%28x%2F3%29+dx+%2B+int_4^5+x+sin%28x%2F3%29+dx+%2B+int_6^7+x+sin%28x%2F3%29+dx+))